# How many DISTINCT vectors we get from pairs v_i + v_j for some set of given  vectors v_i ? 

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

Consider some set of vectors v_i i=1...N , v_i \in Z^k.

e.g. N = 10^4; k = 10

Consider all possible sums: v_i + v_j.

Is it possible to estimate how many  DISTINCT vectors we get in advance without making summation ? (some algorithm ? what is complexity of this algorithm ?)

Obviously maximal number is N(N+1)/2 - when all obtained vectors are distinct. Minimal number is "1" - when all v_i are equal to each other.

======

The question can be reformulated in other terms:
consider polynomial P = \sum_i z^{(v_i)} 
where z^v means z_1^{(v_1)}z_2{(v_2)}...  z_k^{(v_k)}.

Consider P^2. How many monomials we get ? (Is it possible to estimate it looking on P it self).

===

Of course we can ask about growth of triple sums: v_i + v_j + v_k and so forth.

===

Why this is interesting (for me) ? The practical (for me) question is it reasonable to write and start some prog or not ?

If I know that answer is N^4 =10^16 - it will take ~3 years - unreasonable.
If I know in advance that we have much smaller number the prog is worth to write and we get result in reasonable time.

If we have some set of vectors w_p p=1...M and we want to analyse how many distinct
elements are there we need to make ~M^2 compares.
So if w_p = v_i + v_j we need M^2~N^4 compares. But for N=10^4 this is 10^16 which is
beyond say "pentium" abilities - 10^16/10^9 = 10^7 seconds ~ 10^4 hours ~ 10^3 days ~ 3 years...

So the task is hopeless and you do not need to start such a program.
But if I know in advance that the number of distinct vectors is much smaller,
then it is reasonable to wait for the answer.

============

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even the case $k=1$ is interesting. There is much work showing that if the sumset is small then the original set is nearly an arithmetic progression. One early paper on the topic is J H B Kemperman, On small sumsets in an abelian group, Acta Mathematica, Volume 103, Numbers 1-2, 63-88.

EDIT: Here's a much more recent result. Yonutz V. Stanchescu, The structure of $d$-dimensional sets with small sumset, J. Number Theory 130 (2010), no. 2, 289–303, MR2564897 (2010j:11147).

According to reviewer Ping Ding, The author shows the following theorems. Let $K$ be a finite subset of ${\bf Z}^d$ of affine dimension $d\ge2$. If $k=|K|\gt3\times4^d$ and $$|K+K|\lt(d+4/3)|K|−(3d^2+5d+8)/6$$
then $K$ lies on $d$ parallel lines. Conversely, if the set $K$ lies on $d$ parallel lines and
$$|K+K|<(d+2)|K|−(d+1)(d+2)/2$$
then the set $K$ is contained in $d$ parallel arithmetic progressions with the same common difference, having together no more than $$v=|K+K|−d|K|+d(d+1)/2$$ terms.

But there are literally dozens of results about these sumsets, many of them due to or building on the work of Gregory Freiman.

Comment: Thank You ! I did not know that - sound a little amusing that such thing is true.  Is there some continuation of this ? In particular for Z^k ?

Comment: Due mean that work ? 

 Freĭman, G. A. Foundations of a structural theory of set addition. Translated from the Russian. Translations of Mathematical Monographs, Vol 37. American Mathematical Society, Providence, R. I., 1973. vii+108 pp.

Terry Tao & K recent work discusses it. Is it really related to this simple question ?

Comment: @Alexander: yes, this book was an early monograph on the subject. But Freiman is still active in the field. And, yes Tao did a lot related to this in recent years (in particular there is his book with Vu). What you are asking for is for a subset A (let us ignore whether you have repetitions) of Z^k what is the relation between the cardinality of the sumset A+A depending and the structure of A. 
Depending what one wants to know precisely this can be very difficult. Your actual problem seems to be solved, so I won't say more.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear, but I take it you want some sort of sampling method that estimates the number of distinct sums.

I'll answer a more general question.  This method is not as well known as it should be.
Suppose $f:X\to Y~$ where $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $Y~$ is some set.  You want to estimate $|f(X)|$, the number of distinct function values.

Generate $N~$ elements of $X$, uniformly at random with replacement.  Let $K$ be the number of elements $x_i$ in your sample with the property that $f(x_j)\ne f(x_i)$ for every $j<i$.  Then the expectation of $K/N$ equals $|f(X)|/n$, so if $N$ is large enough you can estimate $|f(X)|\approx nK/N$.

In your application, the hard part is the test "$f(x_j)\ne f(x_i)$ for every $j<i$ ".  You don't need to calculate all sums to do that.  You want to find the pairs of vectors with a given sum, so for each first vector do a binary search to find the second. Or something like that, in practice it should be fast with some careful data structure design.

It should also be possible to do it by summing a large random selection of vector pairs then counting the coincidences in their sums.  [This paper](http://www.win-vector.com/dfiles/EstimatingTheRangeOfAFunction.pdf) should give hints.

Comment: But when you sample $n$ vectors randomly they will most likely be in 'general position' enough so that the number of pairs $v_i+v_j$ will be $n(n+1)/2$. Am I mising something?

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I have to caught it yet. But let me comment on some parts. "question is unclear". Let me formulate very concretely. I have polynom "P" with ~10^4 monoms (it comes as  determinant of very simple 8*8 matrix). The question is can I calculate P^2 ?  if you calculate P^2 you get ~10^8 monoms so to find equal among them (in worst case) you need (10^8)^2 time - this is IMPOSSIBLE on current computers. But may be my case is not worst ? May be there only 10^10 monoms ? Then it is possible ! Can I understand how many monoms I will get in advance ? Does it clarify the question ?

Comment: @J.C. Ottem: I assume you refer to my last paragraph. If a fairly large sample shows no coincidences, then you know with a good degree of confidence that the total number of distinct sums is a large fraction of the total number of sums.  You can calculate it, something like the birthday paradox in reverse.

The paper I linked to has some quantitative estimates and neat tricks, so it is probably a better option than crude sampling.

Comment: @Chervov: Yes, that fits the question I answered.  $X$ is the set of pairs of monomials in $P$, with some arbitrary ordering, and $f(X)$ is the monomial formed by multiplying them.  Of course you will only get an estimate; I don't think you can find the exact number faster than multiplying.  Of course all this ignores the fact that monomials can cancel each other out. In rare cases lots of cancellation will occur and $P^2$ will have far fewer monomials the number of distinct products of pairs of monomials of $P$.

Comment: @Chernov: Incidentally, you are saying something wrong.  If you have $10^8$ monomials and you want to find if two are the same, it doesn't take $10^{16}$ operations.  You can do it much faster by sorting them (according to any ordering you please) and scanning the sorted list.

Comment: @Brendan Last comment is great ! Indeed I can do so. 

Comment: @Brendan But the question seems to me more interesting than its origin. Especially see answer by Gerry Myerson.